# return in PHP code

Tags: php

when we use `return` in PHP on global scope, after `return`, does execution just stop?
or processing will go on?

```
<?php

if(defined("A")) return;
define("A", true);

echo "Hello";

if(defined("A")) return;
define("A", true);

echo "Hello";
?>
```

Comment: execution will go on..you need to use `exit` to stop the further execution..

Comment: have a read http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php

Comment: @Mr.Alien wrong. Execution will be stopped

Comment: @AlexanderLarikov Agreed..but I just gave a basic thing that if he uses return he should exit and btw if you read exit in php manual it says `Output a message and terminate the current script`

Comment: @Mr.Alien But there is possible 2 cases: `If called from the global scope, then execution of the current script file is ended. If the current script file was included or required, then control is passed back to the calling file.` But in OP's case execution will be stopped.

Comment: @AlexanderLarikov Ya in this case execution stops, I echoed two different words but I was just able to see echo hello which is first

Answer (score 3):

If you want to stop a script, you'd better use `exit`, because return should be only used in functions !

http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php

In your case, the script will end as said by the documentation : `return will also end the execution of an eval() statement or script file`

Comment: I'm not responsible for that downvote, but the OP did ask about  `return`ing in the global scope. Not in functions.

Comment: Yes after many edits, but in first case it was not indicated !

Comment: @navnav, have you read his first line? AND have you read the function.exit.php manual page? It says `Output a message and terminate the current script` and there are number of examples supporting his answer and absolutely matching the question's context.

Comment: @JasonWilliams Have you seen his edits? Are you aware of the fact that using `return` in the main script will stop execution, so although using `exit;` is a good alternative, it is not vital. My first comment was to his first post. Where he talked about functions.

Comment: @navnav Yes but as you said, look my edits, i always say : "If you want to stop a script, you'd better use exit, because return should be only used in functions !" If you engage user to use some native php func everywhere not in the right context, it's not my problem ... ANd yes i make and edit after the post was edited for more clarity !

Comment: Right, and what makes you think one should not use `return` on the global scope? Quoted from the manual: "If called from the global scope, then execution of the current script file is ended." No where does it say there that `return`ing in the global scope is bad. Unless I've missed something. And if that's the case, **my bad**.

Comment: 'I am aware that execution of script continues' I didn't say that...The execution stops if `return` is used in the global scope. I think you should read my comment again. I know `exit;` can be used, but so can `return`. In this answer, it stated that `return` should not be used in the global scope to stop execution, but instead, it should only be used in functions. When it can be used in the global scope.

Comment: @navnav People who learned me PHP, and most of the web. Tell me you use `return` in global script i tell you that you should use `exit` (like in my post) because it's more integrated in the whole PHP thinking, and you will more see `exit` than `return`. It's only a phylosophical problem, it's not a PHP problem.

Comment: I know @PoulsQ, and I totally agree with you. `exit;` should be used in the global scope, but it's just that you made out as if `return;` could not be used, when that's simply not the case.

Comment: Yes, but i say "because return SHOULD be only used in functions", i didn't say "because return MUST be only used in functions". If it's the same meaning in english, it's my mistake so ... Because for me it was an advice.

Comment: Yes you did say that, but then that was followed by: 'In your case, the script shall go on ...', which was incorrect, making the OP and other readers think that `return;` won't work in the global scope.

Answer (score 1):

Your script will be stopped after first `return`

As [documenation](http://php.net/return) says:

> If return is called from within the main script file, then script
>   execution ends